# Packing items vertically (with fixed length and horizontal position)

Tags: c#, algorithm

Let's say i have some items, that have a defined `length` and `horizontal position` (both are constant) :

```
1 : A      
2 :     B
3 :  CC
4 :  DDD   (item 4 start at position 1, length = 3)
5 :    EE  
6 : F
```

I'd like to pack them vertically, resulting in a rectangle having smallest height as possible.

Until now, I have some very simple algorithm that loops over the items and that check row by row if placing them in that row is possible (that means without colliding with something else). Sometimes, it works perfectly (by chance) but sometimes, it results in non-optimal solution.

Here is what it would give for the above example (step by step) :

```
 A      |  A   B  |  ACC B  |  ACC B  |  ACC B  |  ACC B  | 
                                DDD   |   DDD   |  FDDD   |
                                            EE  |     EE  |
```

While optimal solution would be :

```
ADDDB 
FCCEE
```

Note : I have found that sorting items by their `length` (descending order) first, before applying algorithm, give better results (but it is still not perfect).

Is there any algorithm that would give me optimal solution in reasonable time ? (trying all possibilities is not feasible)

---

EDIT : here is an example that would not work using sorting trick and that would not work using what TylerOhlsen suggested (unless i dont understand his answer) :

```
1 : AA
2 :    BBB
3 :   CCC 
4 :  DD
```

Would give :

```
AA BBB
  CCC 
 DD
```

Optimal solution :

```
 DDBBB
AACCC
```

Comment: It is closely related to the [binpacking problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), which is NP-Complete. However, there is an extra constraint here. My gut tells me it is still NP-Complete, but I am not sure about it.

Comment: In your example of your current algorithm, wouldn't the F fall down to the first row, the A down to the second row, and the B down to the second row?

Comment: no, rows are defined from top to bottom and items are processed in the order they are defined (A, B, ... F). so A and B are placed in first, top row. i edited question to show step by step progression.

Comment: This reminds me of the Office command bars that were constantly stacked up very badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just spitballing (off the top of my head and just pseudocode ).  This algorithm is looping through positions of the current row and attempts to find the best item to place at the position and then moves on to the next row when this row completes.  The algorithm completes when all items are used.

The key to the performance of this algorithm is creating an efficient method which finds the longest item at a specific position.  This could be done by creating a dictionary (or hash table) of: key=positions, value=sorted list of items at that position (sorted by length descending).  Then finding the longest item at a position is as simple as looking up the list of items by position from that hash table and popping the top item off that list.

```
int cursorRow = 0;
int cursorPosition = 0;
int maxRowLength = 5;

List<Item> items = //fill with item list
Item[][] result = new Item[][];

while (items.Count() > 0)
(
    Item item = FindLongestItemAtPosition(cursorPosition);
    if (item != null)
    {
        result[cursorRow][cursorPosition] = item;
        items.Remove(item);
        cursorPosition += item.Length;
    }
    else //No items remain with this position
    {
        cursorPosition++;
    }

    if (cursorPosition == maxRowLength)
    {
        cursorPosition = 0;
        cursorRow++;
    }
}
```

This should result in the following steps for Example 1 (at the beginning of each loop)...

```
 Row=0  |  Row=0  |  Row=0  |  Row=1  |  Row=1  |  Row=1  |  Row=2  |
 Pos=0  |  Pos=1  |  Pos=4  |  Pos=0  |  Pos=1  |  Pos=3  |  Pos=0  |

        |  A      |  ADDD   |  ADDDB  |  ADDDB  |  ADDDB  |  ADDDB  | 
                                         F      |  FCC    |  FCCEE  |
```

This should result in the following steps for Example 2 (at the beginning of each loop)...

```
 Row=0  |  Row=0   |  Row=0   |  Row=1   |  Row=1   |  Row=1   |  Row=2   |
 Pos=0  |  Pos=2   |  Pos=4   |  Pos=0   |  Pos=1   |  Pos=3   |  Pos=0   |

        |  AA      |  AACCC   |  AACCC   |  AACCC   |  AACCC   |  AACCC   |
                                                         DD    |   DDBBB  |
```

Comment: The OP said he tried this but it is still not optimal: `Note : I have found that sorting items by their length (descending order) first, before applying algorithm, give better results (but it is still not perfect).` Can you elaborate on the difference between your approach to his? Or is it the same approach, and the algorithm is not optimal? (and does not answer the question, since he had tried it already)

Comment: (Also, I'd appritiate a proof guidelines that show this approach is optimal, because my gut keeps telling me that problem is NP-Complete)

Comment: The OP said he was looping through items.  I am looping through positions.  That's the main difference in my approach.

Comment: You are correct that he said he tried sorting.  I am suggesting he sorts in a little different way to give a better performance results.  Instead of purely sorting by length, it should be sorted by position (ascending) AND length (descending).

Comment: My algorithm works for both examples you gave in the post.  I will edit my answer with more detail in the steps.

Comment: You are right, your algorithm works (i tried some complex cases and all of them passed the test). Anyway my first algorithm works too and exactly same way as yours if adapted like this : sort elements first by their `position`, then by their `length` (descending)

Answer (score -2):

This is a classic Knapsack Problem. As @amit said, it is NP-Complete. The most efficient solution makes use of Dynamic Programming to solve.

The Wikipedia page is a very good start. I've never implemented any algorithm to solve this problem, but I've studied it relation with the minesweeper game, which is also NP-Complete.

[Wikipedia: Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: **This is NOT knapsack nor binpacking problem**. There is an extra constraint here. In binpacking/knapsack - elements with the same "weight" are identical when it comes to feasibility - in here they are not. An item that starts from 0 and an item that starts from 3 (horizonal) are not identical, even if they both have "weight" (length) of 5. (PS: If any, it is more similar to binpacking not knapsack problem). The constraint might make it an easier problem, and to deduce it is NP-Complete - a reduction must be showed.